# Is it possible to exclude data file sources and intermediary files from bdist?

Tags: python, setuptools

I am using setuptools to build a number of data files (compiled translations,
icons resized and converted into different formats, etc.) and I would like to include the sources of these data files in to `sdist` and the build results but not their sources and and intermediary files into `bdist_wheel`.

When I use `package_data` both sources, intermediary files and built files will be included into `bdist_wheel`.  E.g. translation sources (.ts) are compiled into .qm files then included as part of a rcc bundle, so bdist includes three copies of the translations in different formats and the same happens with icons.

Is there any way to prevent this when using setuptools, i.e. have `sdist` include data files in their source format and `bdist_wheel` include only the built results without the sources?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Include your directories in `MANIFEST.in` (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template)), it's exactly for sdist distribution. Don't use `include_package_data = True` in `setup.py` because that includes files from `MANIFEST.in` into bdist distributions.

Comment: Thanks, that's almost perfect.  Is there an equivalent for bdist that only includes the built files in bdist_wheel but not sdist? Using `package_data` also includes listed files in sdist if they happen to be built.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way for it.

Answer (score 4):

Further down is a minimal example showing how to achieve both:

- packaging a data file `file.src` in `sdist` only;
- and packaging another data file `file.bin` in `bdist` only;
- additionally it shows how `file.all` is packaged in both distribution packages and `file.not` in none of them.

The gist of it is:

- first and foremost, always thoroughly clean up the working directory between two packaging attempts while tweaking these packaging options (in particular empty the `src/Thing.egg-info` directory containing the `SOURCES.txt` file as well as the `build`, and `dist` directories) or the results will be inconsistent;
- set the `include_package_data` option to `True`;
- `file.all` and files that belong in both `sdist` and `bdist` are specified in `MANIFEST.in`;
- `file.bin` and files that belong in `bdist` only are specified in `package_data`;
- `file.src` and files that belong in `sdist` only are specified in both `MANIFEST.in` and `exclude_package_data`;
- `file.not` and files that do not belong in any distribution package are not specified anywhere.

The directory structure for our example:

```
    .
    ├── MANIFEST.in
    ├── setup.py
    └── src
        └── thing
            ├── __init__.py
            └── data
                ├── __init__.py
                ├── file.all
                ├── file.bin
                ├── file.not
                └── file.src
```

In `MANIFEST.in`:

```
recursive-include src/thing *.all
recursive-include src/thing *.src
```

In `setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    package_data={'thing': ['data/*.bin']},
    exclude_package_data={'thing': ['data/*.src']},
    include_package_data=True,
    #
    name='Thing',
    version='1.0.0',
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where='src'),
)
```

This has been tested with:

- Python 3.6.7
- setuptools 39.0.1
- wheel 0.33.1