# How do I include and access package resources?

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have this folder structure:

```
my-package -
            |- src/mypackage
            |- resources/some-resources
            |- setup.py
            |- setup.cfg
```

I want to load `some-resources` from within `mypackage`. How do I do this?
I have read online I should update my `setup.py` to include:

```
setup(
    ...
    package_data={"": ["resources"]},
    include_package_data=True,
    ...
)
```

And that I should then be able to use `pkg_resources` to access my `resource` folder. But the examples seem like they are incomplete, e.g. `pkg_resources.resource_listdir("mypackage", "")` (one suggestion) just lists the python files in `mypackage`. So to reiterate - how do I include `resources` in my package, and then access them from my code?

Comment: Maybe you need `listdir("mypackage", "resources")`?  By the way I could not find `pkg_resources.listdir` in the `pkg_resources` module.

Comment: sorry - yes, that should be: `resource_listdir`. No luck, it just seems to list the contents of the package, which is just the python code.. so I don't know where the "resource" folder should be accessed/if it's even been added with those setup changes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54953494 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58941536