# Include config files with setup.py install

Tags: python, setuptools

I have tried all the option available on stackoverflow, still could not get etc directory to get copied to install path with `setup.py install` command. I have code in below structure.

```
├── setup.py
├── MANIFEST.in
├── etc/
│   ├── config.yaml
│   └── message.xml
└── src/
    └── my-app/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── main.py
```

I am using setuptools version 65.6.3 with python 3.7.5

setup.py

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
  name='my-app',
  version='0.1',
  package_dir=("","src"),
  packages=setuptools.find_packages("src"),
  include_package_data=True,
  entry_points={
    "console_scripts":[
        "my_main = my-app.main:main"
     ]
  })
```

MANIFEST.in

```
recursive-include etc *.yml *.xml
```

I have also tried below in MANIFEST

```
include etc/*.yml
include etc/*.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can not have an importable package named `my-app` with a dash `-`, because it is not a valid name in Python. If I were you I would rename `src/my-app` to `src/my_app` with an underscore `_`. On the other hand you can  (you should) keep the project name as `my-app`. The project name is what you "*pip*-install", and the package name is what you import (see [here](https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/packaging.html) for some more details).

Then, "package data" has to be part of an importable package. So if I were you, I would move `etc` to `src/my_app/etc`.

Look at this other answer for example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54953494